# Rationalising the utility of swap in Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830

Tags: settings

I am trying to get my hands on the average read/write speed(s) of the RAM bundled on the said phone. Just wondering how this faces off with a Class 10 micro SD. I was thinking if the Class rating was high enough, maybe using swap might be a good idea.

Q1.) Is there a Class rating that is performing almost onpar with the RAM random access timing?
Q2.) Is my theoretical basis invalid?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this discussion on MoDaCo](http://android.modaco.com/topic/312453-acer-liquid-ram/page__view__findpost__p__1328456), the RAM throughput of an Acer Liquid is 1.3 GB/s.  Even if the Ace's RAM is slower (unlikely) it's got to be way faster than the Class 10 SD card speed (10 MB/s write).

So yes, your theoretical basis is invalid given that Class 10 is the highest rating.  Even [UHS-II cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Transfer_modes) with a "theoretical" max speed of over 300 MB/s are slow compared to RAM, and few phones support SDXC cards anyways.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I think a typical setup for a decent device these days is [LPDDR1 RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_DDR) ([convenient table](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4062/samsung-galaxy-tab-the-anandtech-review)), which can be considered roughly equivalent to standard DDR SDRAM (which, even in its slowest form, has a peak transfer rate of about 1600 MB/s). You'd have to have both very slow RAM and a smoking fast SD card, methinks.